# Protobuf dart generation on Mac OS doesn't find protoc-gen-dart

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers, protoc

I've installed protoc with homebrew and try to generate dart code with proto files. 
When I tried a simple case like `protoc --dart_out=. test.proto` 
it give me: 

`protoc-gen-dart: program not found or is not executable
--dart_out: protoc-gen-dart: Plugin failed with status code 1.`

But `protoc-gen-dart` is in my path...

I also tried to specify the path like `protoc --dart_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-dart=~/.pub-cache/bin/protoc-gen-dart ./test.proto` but same error...

Anyone know how can I fix this ?

EDIT:

```
echo | ~/.pub-cache/bin/protoc-gen-dart
Unhandled exception:
InvalidProtocolBufferException: CodedBufferReader encountered a malformed varint.
#0      CodedBufferReader._readRawVarint32 (file:///Users/jaumard/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.10.5/lib/src/protobuf/coded_buffer_reader.dart:180:5)
#1      CodedBufferReader.readInt32 (file:///Users/jaumard/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.10.5/lib/src/protobuf/coded_buffer_reader.dart:109:22)
#2      CodedBufferReader.readBytes (file:///Users/jaumard/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.10.5/lib/src/protobuf/coded_buffer_reader.dart:126:18)
#3      CodedBufferReader.readString (file:///Users/jaumard/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.10.5/lib/src/protobuf/coded_buffer_reader.dart:132:39)
#4      _mergeFromCodedBufferReader (file:///Users/jaumard/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.10.5/lib/src/protobuf/coded_buffer.dart:158:47)
#5      GeneratedMessage.mergeFromBuffer (file:///Users/jaumard/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.10.5/lib/src/protobuf/generated_message.dart:159:5)
#6      new GeneratedMessage.fromBuffer (file:///Users/jaumard/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.10.5/lib/src/protobuf/generated_message.dart:31:5)
#7      new CodeGeneratorRequest.fromBuffer (package:protoc_plugin/src/plugin.pb.dart:88:15)
#8      CodeGenerator.generate.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/jaumard/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protoc_plugin-0.10.5/lib/code_generator.dart:66:25)
#9      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1379:54)
#10     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#11     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#12     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#13     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#14     Stream.fold.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream.dart:726:18)
#15     _RootZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1302:10)
#16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:389:13)
#17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399:15)
#18     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:283:7)
#19     _SyncStreamController._sendDone (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:771:19)
#20     _StreamController._closeUnchecked (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:628:7)
#21     _StreamController.close (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:621:5)
#22     _Socket._onData (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:1728:21)
#23     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#24     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#25     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#26     _SyncStreamController._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:763:19)
#27     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:639:7)
#28     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:585:5)
#29     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:1290:35)
#30     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:819:18)
#31     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#32     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#33     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#34     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

And `dtruss` output:

```
 sudo dtruss protoc --dart_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-dart=~/.pub-cache/bin/protoc-gen-dart ./test.proto -I=.
Password:
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available

SYSCALL(args)            = return
~/.pub-cache/bin/protoc-gen-dart: program not found or is not executable
--dart_out: protoc-gen-dart: Plugin failed with status code 1.
open("/dev/dtracehelper\0", 0x2, 0xFFFFFFFFE5D36050)             = 3 0
ioctl(0x3, 0x80086804, 0x7FFEE5D35E60)           = 0 0
close(0x3)               = 0 0
madvise(0x10A24F000, 0x2000, 0x5)                = 0 0
access("/AppleInternal/XBS/.isChrooted\0", 0x0, 0x0)             = -1 Err#2
bsdthread_register(0x7FFF65DE2438, 0x7FFF65DE2428, 0x2000)               = 1073742047 0
sysctlbyname(kern.bootargs, 0xD, 0x7FFEE5D35170, 0x7FFEE5D35168, 0x0)            = 0 0
ioctl(0x2, 0x4004667A, 0x7FFEE5D353F4)           = 0 0
mprotect(0x10A2E4000, 0x1000, 0x0)               = 0 0
mprotect(0x10A2EB000, 0x1000, 0x0)               = 0 0
mprotect(0x10A2EC000, 0x1000, 0x0)               = 0 0
mprotect(0x10A2F3000, 0x1000, 0x0)               = 0 0
mprotect(0x109ED0000, 0x90, 0x1)                 = 0 0
mprotect(0x109ED2000, 0x1000, 0x1)               = 0 0
mprotect(0x109ED0000, 0x90, 0x3)                 = 0 0
mprotect(0x109ED0000, 0x90, 0x1)                 = 0 0
issetugid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)                 = 0 0
getentropy(0x7FFEE5D34A40, 0x20, 0x0)            = 0 0
getpid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)            = 29452 0
stat64("/AppleInternal\0", 0x7FFEE5D355E0, 0x0)          = -1 Err#2
csops(0x730C, 0x7, 0x7FFEE5D35110)               = -1 Err#22
proc_info(0x2, 0x730C, 0xD)              = 64 0
csops(0x730C, 0x7, 0x7FFEE5D34960)               = -1 Err#22
access(".\0", 0x0, 0x0)          = 0 0
stat64("/\0", 0x7FFEE5D33EF8, 0x0)               = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr\0", 0x7FFF65CC0954, 0x7FFEE5D35840)            = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local\0", 0x7FFF65CC0954, 0x7FFEE5D35840)              = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/bin\0", 0x7FFF65CC0954, 0x7FFEE5D35840)          = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/bin/protoc\0", 0x7FFF65CC0954, 0x7FFEE5D35840)           = 0 0
readlink("/usr/local/bin/protoc\0", 0x7FFEE5D34C40, 0x400)               = 37 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar\0", 0x7FFF65CC0954, 0x7FFEE5D35840)               = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf\0", 0x7FFF65CC0954, 0x7FFEE5D35840)              = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.6.1.1\0", 0x7FFF65CC0954, 0x7FFEE5D35840)              = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.6.1.1/bin\0", 0x7FFF65CC0954, 0x7FFEE5D35840)          = 0 0
getattrlist("/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.6.1.1/bin/protoc\0", 0x7FFF65CC0954, 0x7FFEE5D35840)           = 0 0
access("/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.6.1.1/bin/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto\0", 0x0, 0x0)            = -1 Err#2
access("/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.6.1.1/bin/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto\0", 0x0, 0x0)            = -1 Err#2
access("/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.6.1.1/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto\0", 0x0, 0x0)                = 0 0
access("./test.proto\0", 0x0, 0x0)               = 0 0
open("./test.proto\0", 0x0, 0x2)                 = 3 0
close(0x3)               = 0 0
open("test.proto\0", 0x0, 0x2)           = 3 0
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2174 (ID 159: syscall::read:return): invalid kernel access in action #12 at DIF offset 68
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2174 (ID 159: syscall::read:return): invalid kernel access in action #12 at DIF offset 68
close(0x3)               = 0 0
pipe(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)              = 3 0
pipe(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)              = 5 0
fork()           = 29455 0
close(0x3)               = 0 0
close(0x6)               = 0 0
sigaction(0xD, 0x7FFEE5D34C78, 0x7FFEE5D34CA0)           = 0 0
select(0x6, 0x7FFEE5D35FE0, 0x7FFEE5D35F60, 0x0, 0x0)            = 1 0
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2172 (ID 161: syscall::write:return): invalid kernel access in action #12 at DIF offset 68
close(0x4)               = 0 0
select(0x6, 0x7FFEE5D35FE0, 0x7FFEE5D35F60, 0x0, 0x0)            = 1 0
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2174 (ID 159: syscall::read:return): invalid kernel access in action #12 at DIF offset 68
close(0x5)               = 0 0
wait4(0x730F, 0x7FFEE5D34DD8, 0x0)               = 29455 0
sigaction(0xD, 0x7FFEE5D34C78, 0x7FFEE5D34CA0)           = 0 0
getrlimit(0x1008, 0x7FFEE5D36160, 0x0)           = 0 0
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2173 (ID 947: syscall::write_nocancel:return): invalid kernel access in action #12 at DIF offset 68
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2173 (ID 947: syscall::write_nocancel:return): invalid kernel access in action #12 at DIF offset 68
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2173 (ID 947: syscall::write_nocancel:return): invalid kernel access in action #12 at DIF offset 68
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 2173 (ID 947: syscall::write_nocancel:return): invalid kernel access in action #12 at DIF offset 68
```

Comment: Perhaps `protoc` expects the plugins in a special location, and not merely in the `PATH`. Or perhaps you didn’t export the new path.

Comment: From the doc of protoc-gen-dart, it just need to be in the PATH, and I can execute protoc-gen-dart directly so no problem on that side I think :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, looks like `protoc` passes the argument path directly to `execve()`, which does not expand the `~` character to mean home directory. Try this instead:

```
protoc --dart_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-dart=$HOME/.pub-cache/bin/protoc-gen-dart ./test.proto
```

In this case `$HOME` is expanded by the shell before protoc is executed, so it will see the complete path of `/Users/yourname/.pub-cache/...`.

---

**Below are some steps that were used in debugging, they may help others in the future:**

Your second command looks like it should work:

```
protoc --dart_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-dart=~/.pub-cache/bin/protoc-gen-dart ./test.proto
```

Perhaps there is something wrong with the executable. You can try executing it directly:

```
echo | ~/.pub-cache/bin/protoc-gen-dart
```

If it is properly executable, you should get an error message similar to "google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Truncated message." because the data from `echo` is not what the plugin expects. If you get some other error, that could give clues as to why it is not executable.

---

You can also try tracing `protoc` with `dtruss` to find out why the plugin execution fails:

```
sudo dtruss -f protoc ...
```

The `-f` flag is needed to show when protoc tries to start the plugin. There should be a line like this towards the bottom:

```
execve("~/.pub-cache/bin/protoc-gen-dart", ..) = -1 Err#2
```

The error number after `Err#` tells why the execution failed. In my case, it is number 2, which can be looked up in `errno.h` file:

```
grep 2 /usr/include/sys/errno.h

...
#define ENOENT 2 /* No such file or directory */
...
```

Which is because I don't have dart plugin installed. But in your case the error might be something more surprising.

Comment: Hey @jpa thanks for reaching out, I've updated the question with the 2 output, not really understand dtruss output ^^

Comment: @jaumard Hmm, looks like `dtruss` needs the `-f` flag to give useful output. I updated my answer.

Comment: @jaumard Ah, looks like it is the ~ character that is messing it up, updated answer again.

Comment: How dude ! $HOME did the trick !!!! :) thanks a lot ! I'll report this back to the issue of protoc-gen-dart

Comment: @jpa Could you please look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63814928/protoc-gen-dart-program-not-found-or-is-not-executable?noredirect=1#comment112851726_63814928

Comment: @ChristineMeyer Hmm, as a troubleshooting step you could try running a command similar to the start of this answer, i.e. give the full path to protoc-gen-dart on the command line. You can also try running `echo | protoc-gen-dart` to see if it can be executed at all (it should give error like "Cannot parse input", but not "Command not found").

Comment: @jpa I tried what you asked "echo | protoc-gen-dart" but said this: "sh: protoc-gen-dart: command not found"

Comment: @ChristineMeyer Yeah, sounds like it is not in your path for some reason or other. Try executing it directly with full path, and then check e.g. `echo $PATH` to see if the directory is there and written correctly.

Comment: @jpa Now I tried this command in an attempt to use full path to protoc-gen-dart and got this error: https://prnt.sc/uewkd5

I dont even know whether that command was supposed to work or not.

Comment: @jpa Tested echo $PATH and I see this now: https://prnt.sc/uewmur

Comment: Can you please come in my question thread because I shared all the screenshots and everything in there

Comment: @jpa Please help me Im stuck since 3+ days now and its really too frustrating that I cant even begin writing a Hello World like service for Flutter app :(

Comment: @jpa Im new to MacOS + Golang + gRPC so please bear with me

Comment: @ChristineMeyer Yeah, unfortunately I haven't used *any* of those ever :) It was pure luck I was able to solve this question. But it sounds like it might be some basic issue with paths.

Comment: @jpa I didnt tried your first line of code in this answer because I thought "$HOME/.pub-cache" doesnt even exists and just now I checked and it actually is there! and now I get this error, there might be something wrong in writing command: https://prnt.sc/uex4xa

Comment: @jpa and Im actually trying to generate Dart gRPC code, is this even a right way to it?

Answer (score 3):

Possibly tht protoc_plugin for Dart code generation is not installed...
If so, run

```
dart pub global activate protoc_plugin
```